# Why the .d.ts type file will not be output to the out directory

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

Problem Description：

I used the .d.ts type file to define some types, but the editor did not compile it. If it is a .ts file, there is no problem. Is this a bug or is it a problem with my writing?

Problem view：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keM24.png)

Please give me some instructions thanks！

Comment: Declaration files like that are only assistants of the TypeScript compiler to tell what APIs are available. They are not used elsewhere so no need to generate JavaScript files from them.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, i see